# error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi' when using it with git

Tags: macos, terminal, git, vi

I have this strange problem with using `vi` as the editor for `git commit -a`.

Normal flow is: I type `git commit -a`, `vi` appears, I enter my commit message, and then `:wq` to save & exit from `vi`.

This works fine. However, sometimes I make a typo and instead of `:wq` I type `:Wq` (because I use the shift for `:`). Then, when I correct myself and type `:wq` again, `git` gives the following error:

```
error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of `git` and `vi`? I can't repro this with vim 7.3, git version 1.7.11.1.

Comment: @Christopher : vi `7.3` and git `1.7.9.6 (Apple Git-31.1)`, the default ones on Mountain Lion afaik

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`vi` is existing with a non-zero status, although without additional details about your setup, it's difficult to tell why. If you're using a lot of plugins to `vim`, you might try moving your `.vimrc` file to `.vimrc.back` and seeing if you can replicate. There are a [few sources](http://tooky.co.uk/2010/04/08/there-was-a-problem-with-the-editor-vi-git-on-mac-os-x.html) that [discuss this problem,](http://www.dubgeiser.net/blog.php?id=278) including at least [one with a potential solution:](http://telos.co.nz/articles/23-error-there-was-a-problem-with-the-editor-vi)

```
git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/vim
```

I would try removing your `.vimrc` first, however. It seems to cause more consternation.

Comment: Thanks, `git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/vim` fixed it.

Comment: @applOOb's solution is better, since it's not a hack like this one.

Answer (score 28):

As answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22699614/git-commit-messages-lost-by-vi

The real solution is to

```
git config --global core.editor vim -f
```

According to vim documentation - `-f option should be used when Vim is executed by a program that will wait for the edit session to finish`

Comment: Finally... this is the right solution.  It also fixes the problem of hitting `:W` and having git reject your commit message when you subsequently save it.

Comment: A solution that's actually a solution and not some lame workaround! I really hope people that read the accepted answer understand the difference between their normal `vim` invocation and the hack they're using.

Comment: @applOOb might need to use quotes there: `git config --global core.editor 'vim -f'`, otherwise `-f` won't be included.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the golang vim plugins?
This line is causing the vi exit value problem for me:
`filetype plugin indent off`

Removing the whole golang plugin block in `.vimrc` fixed the problem. Installing the golang plugin using fugitive can be as easy as: `ln -s $GOROOT/misc/vim ~/.vim/bundle/vim-golang`

(I just documented the problem in [this issue](https://github.com/jnwhiteh/vim-golang/issues/18) on the [vim-golang github](https://github.com/jnwhiteh/vim-golang))

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with Git config I guess.

So the solution is to reset Git config and it worked for me:

```
git config --global core.editor $(which vim)
```

`$(which vim)` is more flexible than `/usr/bin/vim` (vim executable may not be there for some people)